# Debugging a specified emacs of multiple, when one is frozen

Tags: emacs

Two emacs server are running on my machine

```
$ ps -ef |grep emacs | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
me    4010     1  6 13:52 ?        00:02:58 /snap/emacs/25/usr/bin/emacs --daemon=orging
me    4538     1  3 13:52 ?        00:01:45 /snap/emacs/25/usr/bin/emacs --daemon=coding
me    4622     1  0 13:52 pts/1    00:00:00 /snap/emacs/25/usr/bin/emacsclient /home/me/ORG/os.org -c -s orging
me    4623     1  0 13:52 pts/1    00:00:00 /snap/emacs/25/usr/bin/emacsclient /home/me/ORG/algorithms.org -c -s coding
me    8945  3548  0 14:38 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto emacs
```

The one of  'orging` is frozen,

Upon reading [debugging - What do I do when Emacs is frozen? - Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/what-do-i-do-when-emacs-is-frozen),  I got the solution

```
 pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs
```

How could apply the operation to the specified emacs saying 'orging'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `kill` command and specify the pid of the emacs instance you want, in this case `4010`:

```
kill -SIGUSR2 4010
```